# Value of $\alpha$,$\beta$ and $\gamma$ in given LPP problem

Tags: probability, linear-programming

By simplex method the optimal table of  given LPP problem

> $$Maximize\;\;z=\alpha x_1+3x_2$$
>   subject to 
>   $$\beta x_1+x_2+x_3=8$$
>   $$2x_1+x_2+x_4=\gamma$$ where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 \geq0$

The table is given below
\begin{array}{rrrrrr|r}
          c_j    & \alpha & 3 &0  & 0 & 0 &   \\ \hline
         B.v  &     x_1 &   x_2&   x_3&   x_4 &  solution\\
           x_2 &     1 &   0 &   2 &   -1 &  6\\
           x_1 &      0 &   1 &   -1 &   1 & 2 \\ \hline
            z_j-c_j   &    0&   0 &   2 &   1 & -
\end{array}

**solution i tried**-here it is given that value of $x_2$ and $x_1$ is $6$ and $2$ respectively and i used this in above constraints and get $\beta$ and $\gamma$ which is $1$ and $10$ respectively ,but don't know how to find the $\alpha$

please help

Comment: hint : compute $z_j-c_j$.

Comment: $z_j-c_j$ is given

Comment: Its value is given. But how is it computed ?

Answer (score 1):

Find Dual of the Problem and equate values of min D to max Z..we will get the value of alpha.!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i0Rk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For the $x_1$ column:

$z_j=3, c_j=\alpha$ and $z_j-c_j=0$

$\therefore \alpha=3$